# Why isn't this script actually randomizing as it should be?

Tags: batch-file, random

The code below should take 1 file out of each sub directory in `d:\test` and put them in `f:\source`. It does this but the randomization part isn't working. Each file from each folder gets picked based on creation date, and the last "created" file in each folder is always the ones that appear in `f:\source`.

Any ideas why?

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd D:\test
set t=0
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd "%%i"
    set /A t+=1
    set n[!t!]=0
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
       set /A n[!t!]+=1
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
    )
    set /A "rand=(n[!t!]*%random%)/32768+1"
    copy "!file[%rand%]!" f:\source
    cd..
)
pause
```

Comment: Classic delayed expansion problem. Use `!random!` instead of `%random%`

Answer (score 0):

**All** `%VariableName%` are expanded by Windows command processor already on parsing the entire command block of first **FOR** loop. This includes `%random%` and `%rand%`.

I suggest to use a subroutine to avoid the need of delayed expansion as much as possible and make the code also more simple.

```
@echo off
pushd d:\test
for /D %%i in (*) do (
    cd "%%i"
    call :CopyRandomFile
    cd ..\
)
popd
pause
goto :EOF

:CopyRandomFile
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FileNumber=0"
for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set /A FileNumber+=1
    set "File[!FileNumber!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(FileNumber * %random%) / 32768 + 1"
copy "!File[%rand%]!" f:\source
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cd /?`
- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`